# Search a value in a main-entity's child property of type List<T> in another List<T> and return main entity

Tags: c#, linq

I'm running into a LINQ2Sql problem where Visual Studio suggest a potential fix but that doesn't work.
Imagine following:

I need to return an entity of type IEnumerable
QmmProductionOrderInteruptCardCollection contains a List this again contains a List every Note has a property "Reviewed" of type boolean.

I now want to look for this property in each note where Reviewed is false but return the top entity 
IEnumerable

Now this is my LINQ-Statement which would return IEnumerable without casting instead:

```
return await ApplicationDbContext.Qmm_ProductionOrderInteruptCardCollections
            .Select(x => x.ProductionOrder)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Notes)
            .Where(n => !n.IsReviewed)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Visual studio suggests a casting into type IEnumerable like so:

```
return (IEnumerable<QmmProductionOrderInteruptCardCollection>)await ApplicationDbContext.Qmm_ProductionOrderInteruptCardCollections
            .Select(x => x.ProductionOrder)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Notes)
            .Where(n => !n.IsReviewed)
            .ToListAsync();
```

But when test I get an InvalidCastException

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BIP_Models.Domain.Qmm.QmmNote]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[BIP_Models.Domain.Qmm.QmmProductionOrderInteruptCardCollection]'.

Do you have any thoughts how to solve this?

For a better understanding, this would be the sql statement I'd like to transfer:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM QmmProductionOrderInteruptCardCollections pic 
JOIN QmmProductionOrders p ON p.Id = pic.ProductionOrderId 
JOIN QmmNotes n ON n.ProductionOrderId = p.Id 
WHERE 
n.IsReviewed = 0;
```

Thanks and best regards.
Patrick

Comment: What is declared return type of method?

Comment: public async Task<IEnumerable<QmmProductionOrderInteruptCardCollection>> GetAllWithOpenNotesAsync()
        {
            return await ApplicationDbContext.Qmm_ProductionOrderInteruptCardCollections
                .Select(x => x.ProductionOrder)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Notes)
                .Where(n => !n.IsReviewed)
                .ToListAsync();
        }

Comment: But basically exception says what is happening in you code - you select a list of `QmmNote` and try casting it to enumerable of `QmmProductionOrderInteruptCardCollection`

Comment: Yes those selects are causing the conversion problem but how should I the get the property IsReviewed, when I'm starting in a different Entity?

The sql to achieve this would be like so:
SELECT * FROM QmmProductionOrderInteruptCardCollections pic
JOIN ProductionOrders p ON p.Id = pic.ProductionOrderId
JOIN QmmNotes n ON n.ProductionOrderId = p.Id
WHERE n.IsReviewed = 0;

This is what I want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `Select` here, it performs a projection on an `IEnumerable`, and here you are returning a new type each time.

Instead just use `Where` like this:

```
return await ApplicationDbContext.Qmm_ProductionOrderInteruptCardCollections
        .Where(x => x.ProductionOrder.Notes.Any(y => !y.IsReviewed))
        .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
return await ApplicationDbContext.Qmm_ProductionOrderInteruptCardCollections
        .Where(x => x.ProductionOrder.Notes.Any(n => !n.IsReviewed))
        .ToListAsync();
```

This should return you `Qmm_ProductionOrderInteruptCardCollection`'s which have at least one unreviewed note.

Comment: Oh my good, that was so easy to resolve. 
Got a knot in my brain.
Thank you very much, Guru Stron and Jonathan Barclay!

Comment: @monsee was glad to help!